# Make child elements stretch one third of the parent's width (in a carousel)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

I am working on a (kind of) carousel with items aligned horizontally.

Each of the child elements (there will be about a dozen of them) should stretch *one third* of the parent's width. Three items should be visible at any one time.

I have used Bootstrap 4 and some custom CSS. No JavaScript is needed, the carousel relies on manual scrolling to reveal its items.

Setting `width: 33.333%` for the list items does not work for very small or very large resolutions as you can see. I would also like the items to stretch *full width at extra-small resolutions*.

What is a viable, flex-box specific,  alternative?

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.page-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}

.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #212121;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#carousel {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
}

#carousel li {
  padding: 0 0 70px 0;
  width: 33.333%;
}

#carousel li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

#carousel li img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#carousel li .caption {
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#carousel li h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#carousel li p {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="hero d-flex">
    <ul id="carousel" class="d-flex">
      <li class="col-md-4">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/people" alt="">
          <div class="caption">
            <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
            <p>A true story</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-md-4">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/nature" alt="">
          <div class="caption">
            <h2>Lorem</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-md-4">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/arch" alt="">
          <div class="caption">
            <h2>My neighborhood</h2>
            <p>Lorm ipsum dolor</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-md-4">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/animals" alt="">
          <div class="caption">
            <h2>Into the wild</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
          </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `col-4` class instead of col-md-4. This will keep the div's width at 33.3% for all resolutions of screen

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #212121;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#carousel {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
}
#carousel li {
  padding: 0 0 70px 0;
}
#carousel li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
#carousel li img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
#carousel li .caption {
  padding-top: 20px;
}
#carousel li h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#carousel li p {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="hero d-flex">
    <ul id="carousel" class="d-flex">
      <li class="col-4">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/people" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
          <p>A true story</p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-4">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/nature" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-4">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/arch" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>My neighborhood</h2>
          <p>Lorm ipsum dolor</p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-4">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/animals" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Into the wild</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT**  for ques in comment (Not updating in the working answer)

Try this HTML markup , it should work as expected by you.

```
<div class="hero container-fluid">
    <ul id="carousel" class="row">
      <li class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/people" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum dolor</h2>
          <p>A true story</p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/nature" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/arch" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>My neighborhood</h2>
          <p>Lorm ipsum dolor</p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://placeimg.com/300/200/animals" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Into the wild</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
        </div>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: `<li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">` does not work as expected: list items do not stack at extra small resolutions and do not *stretch 100%* either. What shall I do to make them stretch 100%?

Comment: Because you are not using it correctly, I mean you are not using it the bootstrap way, You have no container div !, no row div etc. I will try fix it, but it may take some time

Comment: Check my Edit in the above answer

Answer (score 1):

An initial setting of a flex container is [**`flex-shrink: 1`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink). This means that flex items are permitted to shrink so they don't overflow the container. That's what you're seeing in your layout.

You need to disable `flex-shrink`.

Instead of this:

```
#carousel li {
    padding: 0 0 70px 0;
    width: 33.333%;
}
```

Try this:

```
#carousel li {
    padding: 0 0 70px 0;
    width: 33.333%;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
```

Or, even better (for greater efficiency), try this:

```
#carousel li {
    padding: 0 0 70px 0;
    flex: 0 0 33.333%; /* flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get **exactly** the desired effect, thanks o 2 members of the community:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.page-wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
}
.hero {
  height: 100vh;
  background: #212121;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
#carousel {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
}
#carousel li {
  padding: 0 0 70px 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
#carousel a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
#carousel img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
#carousel .caption {
  padding: 20px 20px 0 20px;
}
#carousel h2 {
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#carousel p {
  font-size: 10px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="//stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="page-wrapper">
  <div class="hero d-flex">
      <ul id="carousel">
        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
          <a href="#">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/people" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <p>A true story</p>
        </div>
        </a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
          <a href="#">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/nature" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum. Dolor sit amet.</p>
        </div>
        </a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
          <a href="#">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/arch" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Lorem</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum. Dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
        </a>
        </li>
        <li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
          <a href="#">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/600/400/animals" alt="">
        <div class="caption">
          <h2>Into the wild</h2>
          <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</p>
        </div>
        </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```